# Getx dependency keeps conflicting with Flutter SDK

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

Here's my pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  get:

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

dependency_overrides:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Here is the error:

> Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on flutter from
> sdk and getx depends on flutter from hosted, flutter_test from sdk is
> forbidden. So, because getx depends on flutter_test from sdk, version
> solving failed. pub get failed (1; So, because getx depends on
> flutter_test from sdk, version solving failed.)

Answer (score 0):

If this is your actual code, you've mistakenly removed Flutter SDK dependency from it.

To add, see here:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter //You missed this line

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  get:

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Also, that `dependency_overrides` is not needed as you're not overriding anything, you're using the exact same `dev_dependency`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `sdk: flutter` under `flutter`, try this instead:

```
 dependencies:
   flutter:
     sdk: flutter // You need to add this.
 
 # ...
```